# Is there a way to insert HTML code into javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I want to be able to insert `<sub><font size="1">2</font></sub>` into

```
user = {
  name: 'abc',
  id: "THAT HTML"
}
```

Is it possible?

One of my tries:

```
user = {
   name: 'abc',
   html: 'CO<sub><font size="1">2</font></sub> Range'
}
```

Comment: `user.id = '<sub><font size="1">2</font></sub>';`

Comment: "is this possible" questions are usually offf topic for SO, since the answer is usually, "try it." it would have taken less time to try it than it did for you to post a question.

Comment: `font` has been deprecated for a decade ago ...

Comment: Insert it how? The question unclear what you want to happen.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once. my question came after a number of unsuccessful tries. Was wondering if it's even possible or was I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to realize HTML is just text. You could easily do:

```
user = { 
    name: 'abc',
    Id: "THAT HTML",
    html: '<sub><font size="1">2</font></sub>'
}
```

and use the `html` attribute as you please, for example as an `innerHTML` somewhere. The important thing is HTML is just text - properly formatted in a specific way, but text.